# Problem with user account after reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Tags: xserver

After reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and xserver when I try to login into my account I get on login screen again.Now I can login only into user account.What to do?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

open tty1 :

```
ctrl+alt+F1
```

Write your user name and password .

```
sudo chown username:username ~/.Xauthority
```

Note : change username by your username.

Now :

```
 ctrl+alt+F7 to return to graphical
```

Try now.